# Match on Either<,> Needs to Return Type Over ValueTuple from Async Lambda

Tags: c#, async-await, functional-programming, either

I have a validation step that checks the Kafka message is properly formed for the expected event.  This Validation function returns an Either<Left, Right> (Left error message, Right is the message after passing validation).

The next step is to match on the Left or Right.  If Left, create an EventTrace object for the error.  If Right, perform an update of the ID from the message in Mongo using an Async method and then create an EventTrace object from that async call's Either<,> that was returned.

Currently to get an EventTrace back from the match I must do the following code.

```
var errTrace = ErrorStringToErrorTrace.Apply(message).Apply(this.CurrentMessage);
var successTrace = SuccessStringToSuccessTrace.Apply(message).Apply(this.CurrentMessage);

var eventTracer = ValidateStatusEventMessage(message)
            .Match(
                (left) => errTrace(ValidationFailMessage(left.Message)),
                (right) => RouteUpdateMessageToEventTrace(UpdateUnid(message).Result, successTrace, errTrace)
            );
```

The issue with this code is that the .Result on UpdateUnid(message), this is not proper async.

If I try to apply async to the (right) lambda with an await, the return type for match changes from EventTrace to ValueTuple.

```
 var eventTracerTest = ValidateStatusEventMessage(message)
            .Match(
                (left) => errTrace(ValidationFailMessage(left.Message)),
                async (right) =>
                {
                    Either<CommonMessage, bool> update = await UpdateUnid(message);
                    RouteUpdateMessageToEventTrace(update, successTrace, errTrace);
                }
            );
```

I've also tried mapping on the Task returned from UpdateUnid, but end up with async warnings still and needing to use Result and also end up with the smell of having Option<Task<Either<,>>> returned from the map.

```
var mapTest = Some(message).Map(async (key) => await UpdateUnid(key));
```

Any help to fix this async conundrum would be appreciated.

UPDATE: adding repo link to a sample w/ signatures

[Match on Either Async Sample](https://github.com/CarlLanglais/MatchOnEitherAsyncIssue)

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Provided minimal, reproducible example above.

Comment: You cannot leave generic type arguments open (as in `Either<,>` in C#.

Comment: Either<,> was just shorthand for the title and I explained Left/Right inside Either in paragraph 2 and you'd see in the Sample repo link, it's actually returning a Either<CommonMessage, bool>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to communicate with the maintainer of the LaYumba Functional package. One of his suggestions was to have the left return a Task.FromException, this got my type return to be Task, which I then await on to get teh eventtrace object.

```
        var eventTracerAsync = ValidateStatusEventMessage(message)
            .Match(
                async (left) => await Task.FromException<LotusNotesStatusEventTrace>(new Exception(ValidationFailMessage(left.Message))) ,
                async (right) => RouteUpdateMessageToEventTrace(await UpdateUnid(message), successTrace, errTrace)
            );


        var eventTracer = await eventTracerAsync;
```

He had another suggesting fo rusing .Map() over .Match(), which I'll try on the side for my own education.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see

```
async (right) => {
    Either<CommonMessage, bool> update = await UpdateUnid(message);
    RouteUpdateMessageToEventTrace(update, successTrace, errTrace);
});
```

does not return `Task<Right>` because you omit the return in the lambda:

```
async (right) => {
    Either<CommonMessage, bool> update = await UpdateUnid(message);
    return RouteUpdateMessageToEventTrace(update, successTrace, errTrace);
});
```

Update: you need to also have left return Task, like so:

```
var eventTracer = await ValidateStatusEventMessage(message)
.Match(
(left) => Task.FromResult(errTrace(ValidationFailMessage(left.Message))),
async (right) =>
{
    var updateUnidAsync = await UpdateUnidAsync(message);
    return RouteUpdateMessageToEventTrace(updateUnidAsync, successTrace,
        errTrace);
});
```

Comment: I tried adding return at the start, VS gives this error -> CS8030: Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value

Comment: I guess you have to adjust the return type of errTrace to be Task<EventTrace>. If this does not work please provide some signatures. I have a hard time guessing types and signatures here. Do you use language-ext?

Comment: I added a Sample project link in the main which has signatures and analyzers used.  I'm using LaYumba functional.

Comment: Does this work for you? Or what is the issue?